# Construct a ndarray from ndarray according to list of coordinate

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, numpy-slicing

I want to build a ndarray `taget` from `src` ndarray according to some coordinates. Here is an example

```py
src = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)
coordinates = [[[0,0],[0,1],[0,3]],
               [[2,1],[1,1],[0,1]]]
target = src.SOME_API(coordinates)
# expect target as
# [[0,1,3],
#  [9,5,1]]
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this tuple indexing to get values of each set of indices, and then transpose it to get your desired shape:

```
target = src[tuple(coordinates.T)].T
```

output:

```
[[0 1 3]
 [9 5 1]]
```